# What is wrong?(Wordpress(HTML/CSS))

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I dont know what but my posts are colliding with the navigation bar like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VH71.png

Thanks if you can help:)

The navigation bar HTML/php

```
<div>
         <nav class="site-nav">

            <?php

            $args = array(
                'theme_location' => 'primary'
            )

            ?>

            <?php wp_nav_menu( $args); ?>

        </nav> </div>
```

Post HTML/php

```
    <div>
  <?php
    if(have_posts()): 
        while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <h2><a a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <?php the_content(); ?>

    <?php endwhile;

    else :
        echo '<p>No content found</p>';

            endif;
?> </div>
```

Css

```
.site-nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.site-nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}

.site-nav ul li a:link,
.site-nav ul li a:visited {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    border-top: white 3px solid;
    text-decoration: none;

}
```

Im just starting to learn wordpress, and I litterally cant get past this. HELP:)

Comment: Your problem is that your float isn't cleared, you need to use a clearfix. Like this https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your CSS:

```
.site-nav {
  float: left;
}
```

Here's [a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adriancarriger/fjd27sko/) of what your setup might look like minus the PHP, and [here's one](https://jsfiddle.net/adriancarriger/exL5j9Lb/2/) with the fix.

## Full Code

```css
.site-nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.site-nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}

.site-nav ul li a:link,
.site-nav ul li a:visited {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    border-top: white 3px solid;
    text-decoration: none;

}

/* Added this to simulate your window size */
.container {
  width: 360px;
}

/* Fix */
.site-nav {
  float: left
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <nav class="site-nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Logos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Websites</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2><a href="">Welcome</a></h2>
    <p>Hey!</p>
    <p>Welcome to our site.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding

```
float: left
```

to the parent element did not help.

But adding [Clearfix](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) hack helped:)

Comment: Please use comments on your original post, instead of an answer.